# Increment column on duplicate for SQLite & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, laravel-5

I have a table `ice_cream` with two columns a primary_key `user_id` and and int `counter` with default value 0.

I want to insert a `user_id` with `counter` value `1`, and increment `counter` on duplicate.

I am looking for an solution with the the Laravel Database Builder for version 5.6 that works for MySQL and SQLite.

For MySQL I have this solution:

```
 IceCream::updateOrCreate([
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
    ],
    [
       'counter' =>  \DB::raw('counter + 1'),
    ]);
```

However, this won't work with SQLite. I get the following error message:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1
>   no such column: counter (SQL: insert into "ice_cream" ("user_id",
>   "counter") values (12,counter + 1))

For SQLite I have also a custom solution:

```
\DB::select(\DB::raw('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ice_cream (user_id,counter) VALUES (?,0) '), [$user_id]);
\DB::select(\DB::raw("UPDATE ice_cream SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE user_id= ?"), [$user_id]);
```

However this wont work with MySql.

There is a general `insertOrIgnore` method since Laravel version v5.8.33, however I am currently on Laravel v5.6 and an update is currently not possible.

It it possible to create one solution that works for both?

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the field name by backticks? `\DB::raw('\`counter\` + 1')` Both kysql and sqlite use backticks for identifier names.

Comment: @Shadow thanks for the idea, I tried it but I still get the same error

Comment: @CPerkins yes thank you for the hint, I have corrected it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with laravel, but is this a bug in the sqlite implementation for laravel?  Do you actually change libraries and/or set a flag indicating the type of backend when switching from mysql to sqlite?  I ask, because something similar to your sqlite custom solution must certainly be generated for MySQL to properly handle new inserts vs. updates.  Can you get the command/script generated for mysql to compare?  For instance, mysql supports `INSERT IGNORE` whereas sqlite requires `INSERT OR IGNORE` and its strange that it doesn't properly choose between the two.

Comment: @CPerkins I don't think its a bug, I think its just not supported. I have a envirement file, and there I can change the database_driver. For testing I would like SQLite because its much quicker. The MySQL query is identical to SQLite query for insert, they both get `nsert into "ice_cream" ("user_id", "counter") values (12,counter + 1)` but it only works for MySQL. `insertOrIgnore` is only working since Laravle v5.8.33.

Comment: This is very close to another question that asked about unit testing.  The other question insisted that good unit testing practices insisted not touching the original database for various reasons and also wanted to know how to tweak the code to work with both.  If the goal is to be flexible with the backend then it's great you found a solution, but as a testing practice, changing code just to get tests working with a different environment is questionable.  Make sure you don't neglect the primary environment just to optimize tests...

Comment: @CPerkins it would be a big problem if I would have written my code like this: `(if (using sqllit) { // execute sqlite code} else{ // execute mysql code}`. Because then I skip testing the code for production :). But since I am able to use the framework, I don't have to test framework functionality.

Comment: @CPerkins Changing the test envirenmoent in `phpunit.xml` is commen practice. For example, when testing, I want no `QUEUE_DRIVER` and `CACHE_Driver`should be an array and `MAIL_DRIVER` should be log (don't actually want to send out real mails during tests. Using `SQLite` instead of `MySQL` reduces the runtime to 85%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way that works for both MySQL and SQLite:

```
$iceCream = static::firstOrNew([
                'user_id' => $user_id,
            ], 
            ['counter' => 0]);

$iceCream->counter++;

$iceCream->save();
```